# How do I override clicks on rows?

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have a table, each row assigned a unique ID so I can click on the row, grab it with jquery and edit the data for that row. I like clicking on the entire row for convenience and it makes it easier for the user..

In the last column, I have an X which I want to be able to click on to delete that row. Again, it has a unique ID so I can identify each row. My jquery looks something like this..

```
    $('.delrow').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.substr(3);
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?')) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/rowdelete/?delid="+id,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                location.href="/";
            }
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }   

});
```

This should delete the row then return to the homepage. What it does is delete the row then continue on into my edit module with a row id of null since the default action for the row click was to do exactly that. I presume at this point that preventDefault only applies to form actions and thus, won't work in this instance. How can I override the default row click action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `e.preventDefault()`, use `e.stopPropagation()`. Easy.

**Edit:** Now that I'm not using my phone to answer, I thought I'd add a bit more. Stopping propagation might have undesired effects further down the line. For example, what if you want to add an event to `$(window).click()`? Having stopped propagation, this event won't be fired if the user clicks the `x`. An IMO better way is somethink like this:

```
$('.row').click(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('delrow')) {
        return false;
    }
    // edit row
});
```

Then you can either add you're event to the `x` element. You could also put your event in the if statement if you prefer... it's a matter of preference.

Comment: I was hoping it was that easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to prevent other event handlers from occuring so you want either `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` or `event.stopPropagation()`.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

This link may clarify a bit:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)